# What element is causing my accordion to have spaces?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm working on my final project for my HTML/CSS class. I'm trying to (potentially over ambitious) create a collapsible accordion style menu. I've managed to get it hid and only show up with a hover, but for some reason, there is an element causing the boxes to have spaces between them, and I'm unsure how to contain the text in the boxes.  Thank you in advance for any ideas you have!

Screenshot: 
[How to remove the area with the red background?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXEfm.png)

EDIT: Sorry first time posting here, wasn't sure how much code to post.

HTML Code

```css
  

 @charset "utf-8";


/* HTML Styles */



/*Body Styles*/

html {
 background-image: url(../images/sushi_wallpaper.jpeg);

}



body { 
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1040px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background-color: white;
 border: 7px solid rgb(149,54,0);
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: none; /* BODY BORDER, RE-ADDRESS WITH COLORS */
 position: static;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
 
 
/*Navigation Styles*/

nav {
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav.horizontalnavigation li {
/*BUTTON SIZES */ 
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 2;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

nav.horizontalnavigation li a:hover {
 background-color:rgb(255,198,73);
}

/* COLLAPSE ABLE MENU */ 

ul.collapse {
 display: none;
}

 
a.accord:hover+ul.collapse, ul.collapse:hover {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
} 



.collapse > .submenu  {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: red; }




ul.collapse li {
 width: 80%;
 float: right;
 border: none;
 line-height: initial;
} 

 nav.horizontalnavigation > ul > li:hover:nth-of-type(4):after {
 text-decoration: underline;
 content: #collapse;
 
} 

 nav.horizontalnavigation > ul > li:target {
 display: block;
} 

nav.horizontalnavigation a {
 /*"BUTTONS" STYLES HERE */ 
 display: block;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: white;
 border: 3px solid rgb(149,54,0);
 box-shadow: 0 0 1em .3em rgb(255,198,73) inset;
 
}

/* Header Styles */
 
 h1 {
   font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
   font-size: 2.2em;
   font-weight: normal;
   margin: 0.5em 0;
 }
 


/*Font Styles */

@font-face {
 font-family: speedingBrush;
 src: url("../fonts/SpeedingBrush.ttf") format("truetype");
}

cite {
 font-style: italic;
}

/* Paragraph Styles */

p {
 display:block;
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.375;
 text-indent: 8%;
}

 
/*Images Styles*/ 
 
body > header > img.banner {
 display:block;
 width: 100%;
} 
 


/* DIV & Section Styles */

 

/*List Styles */



/*Footer Styles*/


footer {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid rgb(149,54,0);
 line-height: 2;
 margin-top: 15em;
 clear: both;
 
}
```

```html
<nav class="horizontalnavigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="sl_pr_table.html">Popular Types of Sushi</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Where can I get sushi?</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">FREE Sushi Catalog</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="accord">Additional Resources</a>
    <ul class="collapse">
     <li class="submenu"><a href="#">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</a></li>
     <li class="submenu"><a href="#">WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW</a></li>
     <li class="submenu"><a href="#">WWWWWWWWWWWW</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Your screenshot and your code snippet look different.

Comment: We are missing a whole lot of CSS code here. Mission impossible IMO.

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's developer tools to pinpoint what elements have margin or padding?  In most browsers you can right click and Inspect Element to hopefully see what is contributing to the space.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys! Sorry first time posting here and not sure how much information was too much. I added the rest of my CSS here. I did try to use the developer tools to narrow down the element (it says it's li.submenu), which I added the red background to (for visibility) but I'm not sure what about that element is causing it to add a space O.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
ul.collapse li.submenu{
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first time coding by hand and that has been killing me - always something small lol  Any recommendations to contain the text within the boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-bottom: 1em;` and it will solve your issue.

```
nav.horizontalnavigation li {
/*BUTTON SIZES */   
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2;
    padding-bottom: 1em; // <----- This is causing the spacing
}
```